# Heuristics for exact #3COLORING close to the 3-colorability threshold

Tags: counting-complexity, graph-colouring

What are some fast heuristics for exactly counting 3-colorings of graphs close to or at the 3-colorability threshold? Is there literature on the average-case performance for any of these methods?